# Python - Check if a string contains a digit

Tags: python, input

I am making a function that uses a while True loop to ask the user to input a password that passes the criteria; min8-15max characters in length and includes at least one integer. I am stumped on how to properly check the input for an integer.

My program:

```
def enterNewPassword():
    while True:
        pw = input('Please enter a password :')
        for i in pw:
            if type(i) == int:
                if len(pw) >= 8 and len(pw) <= 15:
                    break
        if int not in pw:
            print('Password must contain at least one integer.')
        if len(pw) < 8 or len(pw) > 15:
            print('Password must be 8 and no more than 15 characters in length.')
    return pw
```

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
if not any(c.isdigit() for c in pw)
```

Instead of

```
if int not in pw:
    print('Password must contain at least one integer.')
```

`int` is a type object and you want check the presence of characters 0-9.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions eg:

```
    import re
    password = "hello"
    matches = re.findall('[0-9]', password)
    if len(matches) < 1:
        print "Password must contain at least one integer"
```

Comment: regex is overkill for this task. You could do ``any(digit in password for digit in '0123456789')`` or ``any(char in '0123456789' for char in password)`` with much less overhead.