# Python - gets an error unorderable types: str<> >= int<>

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numbers, printf

A friend of mine is studying Python and gets this error

[image]

```
name = int(input('Type str: '))
if name >= 0:
  print('Typed name is wrong')
elif name <= 0:
  print('Typed name is wrong')

else:
  name1 = str(input('Type your name: '))
  print('Your name is: ' + name1)
```

Of course, I don't understand Python, but when he enters a number, everything works fine, but when he feeds on entering a string value, he gets an error, how can this problem be solved?

Comment: How on Earth could a name be positive or negative??

Comment: If this is what you meant, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205288/python-check-if-a-string-contains-a-digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you use the `input()` function you read input in string form. When you use `int(input())` your string input is typecasted to integer form. If you input anything that can't be typecasted to an integer you'll get an error. 
**For example:** If your input is "3" then it'll be typecasted to 3 and if you input "your name" it can't be typecasted, hence it'll throw an error. 
That's why you didn't get any error when you were typing a number because the typecasting was successful. 
*It'll be helpful if you could elaborate what output you want.*